# AOT build error (ngc)

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, loopback

I get error when **only** building with `--prod` in ionic 3:

`Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda...`

I found out it happens when I use `sdk` folder for login and auth , its `loopback-sdk-builder`... The reason I suspect this happens is because the `sdk` I'm importing does not exist in the project folder of the mobile app. I am looking for an advice, I couldn't find information on internet regarding this.

The `sdk` is built in the website project directory.

the functions I am using are `login` custom service, auth service and also getting some data persisted in localStorage during login process.

Comment: My advice is posting some code that causes the problem

Comment: I'm having difficulties to pin point the code thats causing the problem since the app works fine with `ionic serve` also works with `ionic cordova run/build android`, only occurs when building with AOT `--prod`

Comment: What is this `Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator'`?

Comment: @Sampath I really have no idea...I looked for it but failed to find it. This is the full error `Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ɵmakeDecorator', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol Injectable in /Users/yasir/myApp/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol ɵe in /Users/yasir/myApp/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts, resolving symbol ɵe in /Users/yasir/myApp/node_modules/@angular/core/core.d.ts`

Comment: Remove your `node_modules` folder and try it again.

Comment: didn't help... i removed and installed again